# Magento, position configurable options

Tags: magento

I create a configurable product, but the dropdwon option is located below the image:
[image]

And I want to put it like this one:
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your css. Inspect that div with firebug or whichever you wish and see the class apply the width you want in your browser first if it works then make changes to your css. If you want to add another class to div, then apply the changes. Then turn on template path hints and see from which template file it is coming and do changes there.

Comment: I not changed the css, it's a clean installation with the Madison Store. I just  added a configurable product with the corresponded simplied one.